# The barrier of intuitively using a second language’s word order

Tags: terminology, second-lang-acquisition, word-order

I am learning German and a big hurdle I am facing is word placement. For example, the last half of a sentence is:

> […], aber ich werde es nicht verstehen.
>   (but I would not understand it.)

I know the verb gets kicked to the end; that can be remembered, no problem. My issue is with the thought process behind it.
As an English speaker I keep having issues accepting that the word order in German makes sense to Germans, because I try to get into the mindset of a native because it helps with my learning. But am limited to an English point of view.
I asked around to a couple of my native pals and they basically said that it just feels correct, and any other order would feel wrong.

- Is there a linguistic term to describe this barrier of understanding?
- Can you explain this further for me?
- As I continue to learn the language, will I reach a point where I will “feel” that this the right way, like my friends tell me, or will I not be ever able to because of the fact that it is not my mother tongue?

Comment: The study is called Phrase Word Oder, or simply, [Word Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order), and it is an essential tool for many languages. English also uses W.O. heavily: for example, a phrase *"Word order is a language tool an English speaker is familiar **with**"* also looks unusual for a Slavonic language speaker due to highlighted word (we keep *"with"* close to the object or pronoun). When just studying a foreign language (unlike running a deep research), it's just a matter of memorizing.

Comment: In my experience it's much easier to impropriate German syntax than German lexicon. Read the equivalent of a couple of novels and you'll have the most important constructions reinforced hundreds of times; but the contrasts between closely related words (*erXen*, *verXen*,*beXen*, *usw*) may come up only once or twice.

Comment: You just have to spend time using the language in every way you can, preferably with native speakers (but also reading/writing it). It seems to be a universal experience that what seemed at first a strange system will eventually start to feel normal and natural. All human languages have a system underlying their structure and you just have to internalise this system.

Comment: @StoneyB. Do you really mean "impropriate"?

Comment: @fdb  It's a coinage that was floating around when I was in grad school 40 years ago, signifying something like "incorporate into one's unconscious perceptual categories". I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: You may be interested in [this Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning?referrer=835wheUwogZ-C_x4xA_MDw2).